# iOS- Programmatically set the left and right margins of a subview to be equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, autolayout

I have a view in an iPad app that on full screen mode expands to fill the entire screen and is available both in portrait and landscape.

This view also contains many subviews (like rectangular cards) and a scrollview.

[ I programmatically add these to a content view, that is created programmatically (in a scroll view) calculating frame size of the cards accordingly ]

```
     contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 2000)];
 [contentView addSubview:firstCard];


self.formScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.formScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


self.formScrollView.scrollEnabled=true;


 self.scrollView addSubview:contentView];
 self.scrollView.contentSize=contentView.frame.size;
```

My requirement is that despite orientation all the cards would be aligned one after the other with equal spaces from both the left and right margin.

The cards though of varying height are all equal in width.

So far, this is what I have tried to set them centered horizontally. I added this code snippet in the viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
    [contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstCard
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:contentView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

where contentView refers to the contentView in the full screen view controller and first card is the first subview card

I also set the property

```
firstCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

On running in the simulator, I get disastrous results. The view is weirdly offset and the other cards are all scattered everywhere else.

This does not happen when I do not set the constraints. They look ugly but they are still vertically aligned the way they have to be.

I am quite new to auto layout and iOS development.

I do wonder if any of these problems have to do with the fact that my contentView is a fixed frame?

I keep the contentView with such a fixed frame keeping in mind, the non full screen mode.

Where am I going wrong? I would really appreciate any help and advice.

Thanks.

EDIT :-

I also tried aligning my content view such that it remains centered to the scroll view. Here's code for that...

(That was also a disaster, the content view doesn't even appear on screen)

```
[self.formScrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                         toItem:self.formScrollView
                                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

}

[where formScrollView is the scroll View ]

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to set the vertical constraint for card views. In your case each view's "top" (starting after first view) will have a relation with the earlier view's "bottom". So that they fall after each other vertically. Can be added as below.

```
float verticalSpacing = 20.0f;

nextCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nextCard
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:contentView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                         constant:0.0]];

[contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nextCard
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:previousCard
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                         constant:verticalSpacing]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll keep that in mind when adding cards to content view. However what I also want is that my content view should be centered correctly.

Comment: Also I want to add that I figured out how to get the contentView centered... Just like how I used autoresizing mask for scrollview   contentView.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;